# angular2 kendo UI RTL Languages support?

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

Based on http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/ Im start using kendoui angular 2  components.
I need support in rtl, 
I know kendo ui jquery support rtl Languages by adding css link to "kendo.rtl.min.css" ,
 butdont find a suitable CSS file in kendoui angular2 downloaded package.

Do you know if there is support for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the works, see the following issue:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/93